# #Python Консольная Программа

Tags: python

```
import os
import time

sourse = ['"D:\MyDocuments"']

target_dir = 'C:\Pogoda'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip  -qr {0} {1}" .format(target, ' '.join(sourse))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Копирование успешно!')
else:
    print('Копирование не удалось!')
```

В чем ошибка?
 Пишет: 'Копирование не удалось!'

Comment: В инвертированном условии. Утилита zip возвращает 0 в случае успеха.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в строках маршрутов или сдвоенный обратный слэш, или одинарный прямой.

Также уберите лишние кавычки.

```
sourse = ['D:\\MyDocuments'] 
target_dir = 'C:\\Pogoda'
```

Для отладки можно делать:

```
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}" .format(target, ' '.join(sourse))
print(zip_command)
retcode = os.system(zip_command)
print(retcode)
```